# How to get regional timezone on Compact Framework and then convert UTC date to local date?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile, timezone

How to get regional timezone on Compact Framework and then convert UTC date to local date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateTime.ToLocalTime() method is available on CF, no need to jump through hoops.  Do make sure to use a DateTime constructor that takes a DateTimeKind argument so you can tell it that it's a UTC time, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

P/Invoke [GetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450943.aspx) to get the current timezone biases, then use those to offset the UTC time.

Alternately you could use the DateTimeHelper.[GetTimezoneInformation](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/faaf9f81-f061-625c-7d55-f3099d9386bf.htm) call in the SDF.